# Check if User input already exists in filled cells in row 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently writing a macro to insert a new Column into all Worksheets. It already works, this is just fine-tuning it. I would like my macro to check if the User Input(to name the new column) already exists in another column before that. If it exists, I would like a window to pop up, in which the user can select to create the new column anyway or to enter another name(return to InputBox).

I´m quite sure I have to use a loop and an If branch, but I am not quite sure how exactly.

Line1:

```
Do While ende = False
    Name = InputBox("Name der neuen Spalte")
    Anzahl_Col = Cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To Anzahl_Col
        If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range(i, 1).Value, Name) > 0 Then
            Retry = MsgBox("Diese Spalte existiert bereits, trotzdem fortfahren?", vbOKCancel)
            If Retry = vbOK Then
                Exit For
            ElseIf Retry = vbCancel Then GoTo Line1

            End If
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

        If StrPtr(Name) = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Abgebrochen!")
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf Name = "" Then
            MsgBox ("Bitte etwas eingeben")

        Else
            Exit Do

        End If
Loop
```

### Expected results

The user chooses a name and if that already exists, he gets asked if he wants to continue anyway or to enter another name.

### Actual result

`runtime error 1004 application or object-defined error`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

It looks like you nearly got it... the problem is in the way you are using the Range object:

```
If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range(i, 1).Value, Name) > 0 Then
```

Read more about `Range` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) if needed. Please see below how you can use `Cells` to achieve the same:

```
If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, Name) > 0 Then
```

PS: always good to highlight the line where you are getting the error too, but i assume that's where is going wrong.